# Getting 401 error status from swagger response when providing authentication using oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui

I am trying to setup `swagger` with `spring security` and `oauth2.0` in my application.I have created all the files required for this , i am able to get the `access_token` and also able to `authenticate` using that `token` when trying with `postman`.

but now i need to do the same using `swagger` and i am getting status 401 
and `error: "Auth ErrorTypeError: Failed to fetch"` on swagger.
also when i am hitting the authenticate button i am getting method type options.

i have used `cors` filter in my application and have removed the security for `HttpMethod.options`.

Why i am getting this error? what i have missed in this?

> authorazation server code:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().and().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login","/logout.do").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, 
                "/oauth/token").permitAll()
              // .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new 
            AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout.do"))
           .and()
           .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
    }
```

Resource server:

```
 @Override

public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http
    .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/swagger-resources/configuration/security")
    .permitAll();


    http.csrf().and()
            //.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");

}
```

swagger configuration:

```
@Bean
public Docket edstrumentsApi() {
    List<ResponseMessage> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("500 message")
                     .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
    list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(401).message("Unauthorized")
                     .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
    list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(406).message("Not Acceptable")
                     .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                   .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("backend"))
                   .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                   .build()
                   .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
                   .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
                   .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
                   .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext())).pathMapping("/")
                   .useDefaultResponseMessages(false).apiInfo(apiInfo()).globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, list)
                   .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST, list)
                   .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}

@Bean
public OAuth securitySchema() {

    List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList();
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope(Constants.SCOPE_READ, "read all"));
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope(Constants.SCOPE_TRUST, "trust all"));
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope(Constants.SCOPE_WRITE, "access all"));

    List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList();
    GrantType creGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant( "http://localhost:8081/oauth/token");
    grantTypes.add(creGrant);


    return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i found the cause of the error.
i was creating the cors filter at the resource side instead of authorisation server.

That's why i was getting unable to get the option request on the server.

Comment: same problem, how to solve it?